# action: push: unauthorized to access repository docker harbor registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, registry, nfs, harbor

I’m trying to push to harbor registry 2.2.
It works with ssl and the storage is on locally mounted NFS share.
The error I get is: unauthorized to access repository: test/flask, action: push: unauthorized to access repository: test/flask, action push.

I tried to push with the admin user to project that I’ve created it with.

I tried to change the permission of the nfs share and it didn’t work.

The registry is on compose and not on Kubernetes.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I have exactly the same. No matter what I try, I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same inexplicable issue, just started happening one day after several months with no issues. Required me to explicitly logout of Harbor registry and then login.

1. `docker logout registry.example.com`
2. `docker login registry.example.com`

After this sequence, the "unauthorized to access" went away, and pushes began working again.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody here, my solution is remove `sudo` from command if exists.

`sudo docker pull` --> `docker pull` and try

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and the solution was `docker login registry.example.com` .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the problem was that the username and password that were used in the GitLab pipeline were protected. This means that they were only shared with pipelines from a protected branch like master for example. Since I was testing my changes in the pipeline in a feature branch, all I had to do was to go to variable settings and uncheck the protected flag for harbor user and password so it can be shared with the pipelines that were running from feature branches.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on linux.

If you use `sudo docker login ...`, you need to do `sudo docker pull ...`.

If you don't use `sudo` in the `docker login`, you don't need the `sudo` for `docker pull`.